# django- error while making the filefield optional

Tags: python, html, sql, django

i am trying to a upload file. Uploading is working fine.

Models.py

```
class I(models.Model):
top=models.ForeignKey(T)
imgfile = models.FileField(upload_to='static/Uploaded_Images', blank= True)

class T(models.Model):
    ...
    image_id=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ...
```

The problem is that if i do not upload a file it shows a error. I tried using *blank=True* but it is not working. In other words how to make it optional. I am using HTML input type and not model forms. I saw many similar error but not working.

Am i doing it wrong
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blank=True` means it won't be mandatory for the `form`. It wil still
be required for the database.

If you also want to have `null` values in the database for that specific
field("imgfile"), you have to pass also the `null=True` into the field's 
constructor.

e.g.

> imgfile = models.FileField(upload_to='static/Uploaded_Images', blank=
>   True, null=True)

Keep in mind that for seeing the effect of `null=True`(or any other change on the tables),
you have to drop the specific table and run syncdb again.

Comment: and how should i do it in class T in the above question

Comment: @user2481247 I'm not sure what you want to do in `class T`. The error was generating in `class I` when you didn't attach it an image. Correct?

Comment: @user2481247 Since what I suggest definitely works, could you please be more descriptive in what does not work? Did you drop the database or the table after you changed the field? What is the error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32817/discussion-between-user2481247-and-rantanplan)

Comment: @user2481247 What's the problem?